# How to map class value inside a class using LINQ Select?

Tags: c#, linq, new-operator

I want to map properties of class which is used as property to a class to another class using LINQ `Select`:

```
var matches = DirectList
    .Select(x => new SearchResult
                 {
                     Name = x.Name
                     Code = x.Code,
                     Description = x.Description
                 });

public class SearchResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Liability Liability { get; set; }
}

public class Liability 
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Here I want to remove `Code` and `Description` as *individual properties* and want to map it to `Liability` class `Code` and `Description` properties.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can try *nested creation* then:

```
var matches = DirectList
  .Select(x => new SearchResult {
     Name = x.Name,
     Liability = new Liability() {   // We create Liability instance and set
       Code = x.Code,                // Code 
       Description = x.Description,  // and Name
     }, 
   });
```

Side note: if you don't want to *edit* `SearchResult` once you have created it, you may want to change `set` into `init`:

```
// Code and Description are moved into Liability
public class SearchResult
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public Liability Liability { get; init; }
}
```